# unable to start mananged server - weblogic12.2.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c, application-server

I have installed weblogic12.2.1, i can able to start the admin server. I have created a managed server from console.
Issue is managed server is not getting started. When giving the below command to start the mananged server, it is throwing the error message on the command prompt.

command to start managed server:

```
C:\WebLogic12c\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startManagedWebLogic.cmd myManagedServer http://usndcwncn149p99:7001/console
```

Error message when executed the above command to start the mananged server:

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 6 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.messaging.interception.MessageInterceptionService errors were fo
und
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.messaging.interception.MessageInterceptionService

A MultiException has 6 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.messaging.interception.MessageInterceptionService errors were fo
und
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.messaging.interception.MessageInterceptionService

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:232)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
```

I tried the below steps to overcome this issue but still could not able to start the managed server.

1)Edited the boot.properties file present in C:\WebLogic12.2.1\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security and maually typed and assigned the username and password.
2)Removed ldap folder from C:\WebLogic12.2.1\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\myManagedServer\data

Did any one faced this issue before and got resolved, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set WLS_USER and WLS_PW variables in startManagedWebLogic.cmd

```
set WLS_USER=myUsername
set WLS_PW=myPass
```